# Doubt in definition of natural transformation between functors

Tags: category-theory

In [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_transformation), the definition of natural transformation as follows:

Given categories $C$ and $D$ and functors $F,G: C ⇒ D$, a natural transformation $\eta: F ⇒ G$ is a family of morphism satisfying the following:

- The natural transformation must associate, to every object $X$ in $C$, a morphism $\eta _{X}:F(X)\to G(X)$ between objects of $D$.
- For every morphism $f:X \to Y$ in $C$, $\eta_Y \circ F(f) = G(f) \circ \eta_X$.

So from what I understand, $\eta$ is a class of morphisms in $D$ which satisfies certain naturality conditions. (So, $\eta$ need not be a set).

Now, let us denote the collection of all natural transformations between functors $F$ and $G$ by $Nat(F,G)$. Is $Nat(F, G)$ a class?

Assuming [NBG axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Von_Neumann%E2%80%93Bernays%E2%80%93G%C3%B6del_set_theory#Category_theory), a member of a class is a set. But $\eta$ need not be a set? I think I am missing something simple here. Either I have misunderstood the definition of natural transformation or confused about NBG axioms.

Also in Riehl's *Category Theory in Context* (pg.57), the author states the following:

> As C is locally small but not necessarily small, a priori the
> collection of natural transformations $Nat(C(c, −), F)$ might be
> large. However, the bijection in the Yoneda lemma proves that this
> particular collection of natural transformations indeed forms a set.

I would agree with this if $Nat(C(c, −), F)$ is a class (by replacement axiom). I personally think I messed up the definition of natural transformations. I would be grateful if someone could clarify my doubt.

Comment: I don't know enough about the NBG framework, but with a requirement that elements of a class are sets it seems like this is not the right framework to do category theory in. For a starter, you want to have a (large) category of small categories and a (very large) category of large categories, and their $(2,1)$-categorical analogues. Given this, why not work with something like a chain of Grothendieck universes?

Comment: I agree with Daniel. But this should be posted as an answer, it is not a clarification comment. See **[How do comments work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19756)** for more information.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Is it an answer to the question? I would think an answer to this question explains how to work in the NBG-framework to still set up a way to do category theory, as the linked Wikipedia page mentions that it can be used in category theory and OP works in it. Instead, I just said that I wouldn't follow the path that leads to this question in the first place.